# Unterminated string constant error when passing sitename to the javascript function

Tags: c#, javascript

when user clicks on the Edit button on the grid I am passing sitename and order id(hidden value) to the javascript function. I am getting "Unterminated string constant error" for one sitename. I dont know whats wrong in that. Please see the Image below.[image]

```
protected void gvCktMap_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Session["TaskID"] != null)
            {
                int intTskID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["TaskID"]);
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "taskListRow");
                }
                CheckBox chkBoxOne = (CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkSelect");
                Label lblREJ = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblREJ");
                // Label lblDesc = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDesc");
                Label lblStatus = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTaskStatus");
                Label lblDaysUntillPTD = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblDaysUntilPTD");
                Label lblPastDue = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblPastDue");
                if (lblStatus != null)
                {
                    if (lblStatus.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "complete" || lblStatus.Text.Trim().ToLower() == "not_required")
                        chkBoxOne.Enabled = false;
                }
                //Do Not move this code...We are selecting orderids based on checkbox enable or not....//Babu//
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {
                    LinkButton lnkSiteName = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkSiteName");
                    Label lblServiceOrderNumber = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblServiceOrderNumber");
                    LinkButton lnkCMNumber = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkCORECMNumber");
                    LinkButton lnkSiteCMTicketNumber = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkSiteCMTicketNumber");
                    LinkButton lnkSMNumber = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkSMTicketNumber");
                    LinkButton lnkSiteSMTicketNumber = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkSiteSMTicketNumber");
                    Label lblorderId = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblorderId");
                    Label lblsId = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblsId");
                    Label lblsiteId = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblsiteId");
                    Label lbllob = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblLOB");
                    Label lblclarifyAccountNumber = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblclarifyAccountNumber");
                    Label lblTaskStatus = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblTaskStatus");
                    LinkButton lnkCustomerName = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkCustomerName");
                    LinkButton lnkProjectName = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkProjectName");
                    LinkButton lnkRoeID = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkPreSaleAssociation");
                    ImageButton detailsbutton = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnDetails");
                    LinkButton lnkpendingdependencies = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkPendingDependencies");
                    LinkButton lnknotes = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkNotes");
                    LinkButton lnkuserpendingdependencies = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkUserPendingDependences");
                    LinkButton lnkPendJeopCount = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkPendJeopCount");
                    LinkButton lnkPreSaleAssociation = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkPreSaleAssocation");
                    LinkButton lnktaskowner = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkTaskOwner");
                    LinkButton lnkConfigs = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkConfigFiles?");
                    LinkButton lnkCircuits = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkCircuits");
                    LinkButton lnkOptics = (LinkButton)e.Row.FindControl("lnkOptics");
                    ImageButton btnMixedorder = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("btnMixedOrd");
                    ImageButton edit_button = (ImageButton)e.Row.FindControl("edit_button");
                    if (edit_button != null)
                        edit_button.OnClientClick = "StoreOrderIDAndLOB('" + lblorderId.Text + "','" + lbllob.Text + "')";

                    if (lnkConfigs != null)
                        lnkConfigs.OnClientClick = "StoreConfigs('" + lblsId.Text + "','" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";

                    if (lnktaskowner != null)
                        lnktaskowner.OnClientClick = "StoreTaskOwner('" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "','" + lnktaskowner.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "','" + lblorderId.Text + "','" + lbllob.Text + "','" + lblTaskStatus.Text + "')";

                    if (lnkSiteName != null)
                        lnkSiteName.OnClientClick = "StoreLnkSiteName('" + lblorderId.Text + "','" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";

                    if (detailsbutton != null)
                        detailsbutton.OnClientClick = "Storedetails('" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";

                    if (lnkCMNumber != null)
                        lnkCMNumber.OnClientClick = "StoreCMNumber('" + lnkCMNumber.Text + "', '" + lblorderId.Text + "')";

                    if (lnkSiteCMTicketNumber != null)
                        lnkSiteCMTicketNumber.OnClientClick = "StoreSiteCMTicketNumber('" + lnkSiteCMTicketNumber.Text + "', '" + lblorderId.Text + "')";

                    if (lnkSMNumber != null)
                        lnkSMNumber.OnClientClick = "StorelnkSMNumber('" + lnkSMNumber.Text + "', '" + lblorderId.Text + "')";

                    if (lnkSiteSMTicketNumber != null)
                    {
                        lnkSiteSMTicketNumber.OnClientClick = "StorelnkSiteSMTicketNumber('" + lnkSiteSMTicketNumber.Text + "', '" + lblorderId.Text + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnkpendingdependencies != null)
                    {
                        lnkpendingdependencies.OnClientClick = "StoreOrderId('" + lblorderId.Text + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnknotes != null)
                    {
                        lnknotes.OnClientClick = "StoreNotes('" + lblorderId.Text + "','" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnkuserpendingdependencies != null)
                    {
                        lnkuserpendingdependencies.OnClientClick = "StoreUserpendingdependencies('" + lblorderId.Text + "','" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnkPendJeopCount != null)
                    {
                        lnkPendJeopCount.OnClientClick = "StorePendJeopCount('" + lblorderId.Text + "','" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnkProjectName != null)
                    {
                        lnkProjectName.OnClientClick = "Storeprojectname('" + lnkProjectName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnkCustomerName != null)
                    {
                        lnkCustomerName.OnClientClick = "StoreCustomername('" + lnkCustomerName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnkPreSaleAssociation != null)
                    {
                        lnkPreSaleAssociation.OnClientClick = "StorePreSaleAssociation('" + lblorderId.Text.Trim() + "','" + lblsId.Text.Trim() + "','" + lblTaskStatus.Text.Trim() + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnkCircuits != null)
                    {
                        lnkCircuits.OnClientClick = "StoreCircuitsInfo('" + lblorderId.Text + "','" + lblsiteId.Text + "','" + lbllob.Text + "','" + lblclarifyAccountNumber.Text + "','" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";
                    }
                    if (lnkOptics != null)
                    {
                        lnkOptics.OnClientClick = "StoreOpticsInfo('" + lblsId.Text + "','" + lnkSiteName.Text.Replace("'", "&apos") + "')";
                    }
                    if (btnMixedorder != null)
                    {
                        btnMixedorder.OnClientClick = "StoreMixedorder('" + lblServiceOrderNumber.Text + "')";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
            log.Warn("Logging:" + ex);
        }
    }
```

How to resolve this error?

```
function StoreOrderIDAndLOB(sender) {
//get handle to parent row:
var oRow = sender;
while (oRow && oRow.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "tr")
    oRow = oRow.parentNode;

//something might be wrong, sanity check:
if (!oRow)
    return;

//build array of all possible elements we have to look into:
var elements = [];
var arrSpans = oRow.getElementsByTagName("span");
for (var i = 0; i < arrSpans.length; i++)
    elements.push(arrSpans[i]);

//site name is the sender, grab its contents:
var siteName = "";
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if (element.id.indexOf("lnkSiteName") >= 0) {
        siteName = element.innerHTML;
        break;
    }
}
siteName = sender.innerHTML;

//find the order ID by looking for matching element:
var orderId = "";
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];
    if (element.id.indexOf("lblorderId") >= 0) {
        orderId = element.innerHTML;
        break;
    }
}

//here you can use the values same way you use in the original code...
alert("site name: " + siteName + " and order ID is " + orderId);
```

}

Comment: post the edit button click handler.

Comment: This means the site name has quotes in it, you will have to replace quotes in the server side language.

Comment: have you tried to debug it with [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/)?  You've got Firefox I see.

Comment: In firefox its not throwing any error.

Comment: Actually its showing that error when loads not when user clicks edit button. Sorry for that. In row databound event I am passing sitename and project name and customername to javascript function.

Comment: Have you looked at line 393 in details.aspx (ie where the error message says the error is) to see if there is indeed an unterminated string there? Because, that might be a good first step. I say this only because you don't seem to have put the line that the error is on in your question... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enough that one value will contain double quotes, and the whole thing breaks since the output itself is broken in such case.

Instead of sending the raw value to the JavaScript functions, let the functions find the values they need. I will give example for one function, you can apply the same logic in all others and have clean code without quotes risk.

JavaScript:

```
function StoreLnkSiteName(sender) {
    //get handle to parent row:
    var oRow = sender;
    while (oRow && oRow.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "tr")
        oRow = oRow.parentNode;

    //something might be wrong, sanity check:
    if (!oRow)
        return;

    //build array of all possible elements we have to look into:
    var elements = [];
    var arrSpans = oRow.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var i = 0; i < arrSpans.length; i++)
        elements.push(arrSpans[i]);

    //site name is the sender, grab its contents:
    var siteName = sender.innerHTML;

    //find the order ID by looking for matching element:
    var orderId = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var element = elements[i];
        if (element.id.indexOf("lblorderId") >= 0) {
            orderId = element.innerHTML;
            break;
        }
    }

    //here you can use the values same way you use in the original code...
    alert("site name: " + siteName + " and order ID is " + orderId);
}
```

Then the required C# is simply:

```
lnkSiteName.OnClientClick = "StoreLnkSiteName(this)";
```

No need to replace, no need to fear quotes.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/PvT3D/).

If you ever decide to use jQuery, the JavaScript code can be drastically simplified, but it can be achieved with pure JS as well.

Comment: how to find text in anchor tag? and im making order id column is visible false. bcoz of that its not getting the order id. If I am making order id column visible true then its working fine. How to get order id when visible false and how to get the text of anchor tag?

Comment: Instead of making it `Visible=false` make it `style="display: none;"` and it will be still hidden, but accessible to JavaScript. To search anchor tags as well, add such lines to the code: `var arrAnchors = oRow.getElementsByTagName("a"); for (var i = 0; i < arrAnchors.length; i++) elements.push(arrAnchors[i]);`

Answer (score 0):

This means your parameter is being passed incorrectly. Can you paste your code? Have you tried setting a breakpoint to see what's getting passed?

Comment: Actually its showing that error when page loads not when user clicks edit button. Sorry for that. In row databound event I am passing sitename and project name and customername to javascript function